# Why do I get Syntax error when accessing a column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using dict(zip(df... to create a dictionary and I get the error below. I've used it exactly in the       same way on a different file and it's working fine so not sure why I'm getting this error in here.

To read the mapping file:

```
df_Mapping = pd.read_excel(r"Z:\Source_Data\Concur_Mapping.xlsx")
```

To create the dictionary:

```
dict(zip(df_Mapping.Claim Sub-Type, df_Mapping.Mapping))
```

Error:

> Cell In[71], line 1
> dict(zip(df_mapping.Claim Sub-Type, df_mapping.Mapping))
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

I was expecting to create a dictionary to replace values in another dataframe

Comment: What is `Sub-Type` supposed to mean after `df_mapping.Claim`? Did you mean something like `df_mapping["Claim Sub-Type"]`?

Comment: Is `.Claim Sub-Type` supposed to be an attribute name?  Because it isn't.  You've got an embedded space and minus sign in there.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! df_mapping is the name of the data frame and Claim Sub-Type is the column name. In the past I used it like the below and it did work   dict(zip(df.Old, df.New)) df being the dataframe and Old, New the name of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, it is because of that space in your column name.

Try:

```
dict(zip(df_Mapping["Claim Sub-Type"], df_Mapping["Mapping"]))
```